# How do I hide a matrix column?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, rdl

I have a matrix in SSRS 2008R2.
It has the following features:

- 2 Row Groups (X,Y from let to right as you look at the report)
- 1 Column Group (Date)
- Y is toggled via X; and when first rendered Y groups will not be visible

I'd like *all column Y* to be initially Visible=False, then if a user expands *any* of the items in column X, say group item Q, then column Y becomes visible, and all the items in Y associated with Q are also visible.

I understand about using the (Static) columns to expose the column vibility property and I've created a Boolean variable IsYvisible, and used this in the property so that there is now a radio button which switches the column visibility - **I want the visibility of column Y to be toggled whenever a user clicks on any of the "+" signs in column X.**

Comment: A screenshot of your groups and columns would help a lot. Is Row Group Y a child or a sibling of Row Group X? Is Column X related to Row Group X? Column Y related to Row Group Y?

Comment: (hmmm!)..is it easy to add screenshots to stackOverflow posts?!

Comment: Yes it's easy to add screenshots. When you edit your question, there will be a small image icon. Clicking on that will allow you to attach an image from your machine. I believe this is available to all users with more than 10 rep.

Answer (score -1):

Select the tablix and right-click the grey button at the top of your Y column, then select 'Column Visibility'.

Use that for your hide/show/display toggle settings, it sounds like you hid the text boxes inside the column resulting in your blank space.

Comment: this suggestion creates an error. I feel that the answer will be more involved than this. I'm hiding/toggling the columns by using the Group Properties of Y and Z

Comment: Error message as follows:      "An error occured during local report processing. The definition of the report '/xxx' is invalid. The tablix has 'Y' as a toggle item. Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a parent"